# Left Outer Join two data tables - VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq

How can I join two data tables using linq. I want to return all orders with canceled status flag.

**Order Table**

```
    ItemNum OrderNum
1   Item1   101
2   Item2   102
```

**Order Log Table**

```
    ItemNum OrderNum    IsCanceled
1   Item2   102         1
```

**Final Result**

```
    OrderNum    ItemNum  IsCanceled
1   101         Item1    0
2   102         Item2    1
```

Here is the demo;

https://rextester.com/RQQZJ4470

I have tried this so far with no luck;

```
 Dim result = From b In backOrders.AsEnumerable()
                         Join c In backOrdersCanceledItems.AsEnumerable() On
                    c.Field(Of Integer)("DistNum") Equals b.Field(Of Integer)("DistNum") And c.Field(Of String)("OriginalOrderNum") Equals b.Field(Of String)("OriginalOrderNum")
                         Select New With {.OriginalOrderNum = b.Field(Of String)("OriginalOrderNum"),
                    .DistNum = b.Field(Of Integer)("DistNum"), .ItemNum = b.Field(Of String)("ItemNum"),
                    .IsCanceled = c.Field(Of String)("IsCanceled")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you just need to do a left join in LINQ:

```
Dim result = From b In backOrders.AsEnumerable()
             Group Join c In backOrdersCanceledItems.AsEnumerable() On
                c.Field(Of Integer)("DistNum") Equals b.Field(Of Integer)("DistNum") And c.Field(Of String)("OriginalOrderNum") Equals b.Field(Of String)("OriginalOrderNum") Into cj = Group
             From c In cj.DefaultIfEmpty
             Select New With {
                .OriginalOrderNum = b.Field(Of String)("OriginalOrderNum"),
                .DistNum = b.Field(Of Integer)("DistNum"),
                .ItemNum = b.Field(Of String)("ItemNum"),
                .IsCanceled = If(c?.Field(Of String)("IsCanceled"), "0") }
```

See my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) for C# versions.

Comment: Isn't IsCanceled as Char?

Comment: @Mary it is in SQL, but that is not how the original post's C# code translated it.

Comment: @user1263981 You said "I have tried this with no luck" in your original question - did you get an invalid cast error on your code?